# WordPress Ajax TinyMCE dropdowns not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, tinymce-4

After much effort I have Tinymce working in a file called via ajax within WordPress. However, the dropdown menus will not function.

Here is my JS code which IS causing the tinymce to capture my textfield.  It is working perfectly.

None of the drop downs work. The color picker, format, view etc drop down menus will not drop down. So this is my issue at present.

Here is my loading tinymce code:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'tinymce_js', includes_url( 'js/tinymce/' ) . 'wp-tinymce.php', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
```

Here is my JS code

```
`jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    textareaId='c_tfield1';
    tinymce.init({
        mode : "specific_textareas",
        content_css : "PLUGINS_URL/cm-core/both-ends/css/tinymce.css",
        elements : 'pre-details',
        editor_selector : "tinymce",
        skin: "lightgray",
        statusbar : false,
        plugins: "textcolor colorpicker",
        textcolor_cols: "5",
        browser_spellcheck: true,
        toolbar: [
            "bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright | bullist numlist outdent indent | undo redo | forecolor backcolor"
        ],
        setup: function(editor) {
        editor.on('blur', function(e) {
           jQuery('#c_tfield1').html(tinymce.get('c_tfield1').getContent());
           jQuery("#c_tfield1").trigger('focusout');
        });
    },
    style_formats: [
        { title: 'Bold text', inline: 'strong' },
        { title: 'Red text', inline: 'span', styles: { color: '#ff0000' } },
        { title: 'Red header', block: 'h1', styles: { color: '#ff0000' } },
        { title: 'Badge', inline: 'span', styles: { display: 'inline-block', border: '1px solid #2276d2', 'border-radius': '5px', padding: '2px 5px', margin: '0 2px', color: '#2276d2' } },
        { title: 'Table row 1', selector: 'tr', classes: 'tablerow1' }
      ],
      formats: {
        alignleft: { selector: 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table,img', classes: 'left' },
        aligncenter: { selector: 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table,img', classes: 'center' },
        alignright: { selector: 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table,img', classes: 'right' },
        alignfull: { selector: 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table,img', classes: 'full' },
        bold: { inline: 'span', 'classes': 'bold' },
        italic: { inline: 'span', 'classes': 'italic' },
        underline: { inline: 'span', 'classes': 'underline', exact: true },
        strikethrough: { inline: 'del' },
        customformat: { inline: 'span', styles: { color: '#00ff00', fontSize: '20px' }, attributes: { title: 'My custom format' }, classes: 'example1' },
      },
     paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste : true,
        paste_postprocess : function( pl, o ) {
            o.node.innerHTML = o.node.innerHTML.replace( /&nbsp;+/ig, " " );
        }
    });
    setTimeout(function(){
        if (tinymce.editors.length > 0) {
            tinymce.execCommand('mceFocus', true, textareaId );
            tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor',true, textareaId);
            tinymce.execCommand('mceAddEditor',true, textareaId);
        }
     }, 500);
});`
```

I have created a youtube video for you to see the improper behavior.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=58_jIV4vRZE

You'll notice the dropdowns are not responsive. They also do not throw any errors in console or php log.

Thanks in advance.

Jay

Comment: Firstly, format your code so that it shows up as code in your post. Secondly, you do not need to make a youtube video to demonstrate the problem: you simply need to explain the error here. I appreciate the effort you put in, but still, explaining the question is the right way to go about asking questions in StackOverflow. Alternatively, you can post images of your screen too, if you wish.

Comment: Are you using a jQuery modal dialog to show TinyMCE?

Comment: Yes Michael. 

We are using this one in particular http://ignitersworld.com/lab/modalBox.html 

Thanks for your interest in this post. 

Jay